# How many four digit integer number exist that that the digits are either NOT in decreasing order or NOT in increasing order?(check my solution)

Tags: combinatorics

Here is a part two of a question, which is homework and I want to make sure of my answer:

A) [How many integer numbers with four distinct digits exist that they are either additive or reductive (check my answer)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3731390/620637)

B)How many four digit integer number exist that that the digits are either Non-decreasing (like 1347,1226,7778) or Non-increasing order (like 6421,6622,9888) ?

My solution for Non-decreasing part :
The digits can be repeated so we can construct a four digit number with 4 or 3 or 2 or even one number .
By picking 4 numbers out of 9 ( except 0 , because logically it cannot be anywhere in that four digit) there is only one arrangement that matches the property (like 1234)by picking 3 numbers out of 9 there is three arrangements(like 1233,1223,1123) by picking 2.....by picking 1....
So the answer would be like :
$$1{9\choose 4}+ 3{9\choose 3}+ 1{9\choose 2}+ 1{9\choose 1}$$

For the Non-increasing part its the same except 0 can be involved as one last or two last or three last ones.
So we have :
${9\choose 3}+ {9\choose 2}+ {9\choose 1}$
So the final answer for the increasing part would be :

$$1{9\choose 4}+ 4{9\choose 3}+ 2{9\choose 2}+ 2{9\choose 1}$$

THE FINAL ANSWER FOR PART B is sum of this two answers  and because of the OR in the question we have to reduce the common answers in our final answer because we count it twice .
The common answers are 1111,222,...,9999
So the final answer is :

$$2{9\choose 4}+ 7{9\choose 3}+ 3{9\choose 2}+ 3{9\choose 1} -9$$

Am I missing somthing or doing something wrong ?
I would really appreciate someone check my answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Total minus increasing minus decreasing plus constant?

Comment: Also, your calculation is wrong. You have only chosen the digits, they must be arranged as well.

Comment: @user675453 if i want to construct a four digit number with any four integer(like 1,2,3,4) there is 4! Possibilities but only one of them is in increasing oder (1234)

Comment: See the case with 2 digits, these are possible combinations, $(3,1), (2,2) , (1,3)$  here number in ordered pair represents number of times a digit  is repeated.

Comment: @user675453 i think you are misunderstanding what the question mean by  “Not increasing” and “Not decreasing “ . Numbers like 3294 are not accepted and if we do what you said in the first comment they would be counted.please read the examples of those parts again .

Comment: @Carlo Oh you are right about choosing 0 in non-increasing part , if we have only one 0 (logically the last one ) it is like abc0 or aab0 or abb0 or aaa0 and with two 0s involved we have ab00,aa00, and with three 0s invloved a000.

Comment: @Carlo so with the same logic that we used in nom-decreasing part we can say if 0 is involved there are ${\binom 9 3}+2{\binom 9 2}+{\binom 9 1}+{\binom 9 2}+{\binom 9 1}+{\binom 9 1}$ possibilities. Now if we want to calculate non-increasing part we have to add this to the answer which 0 is not involved (which is the same as non-decreasing) . What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let find a correct solution and compare with your numbers.

Obviously a quadruple of numbers can be brought in non-increasing (non-deacreasing) order in a unique way. Therefore it is required only to know how many copies of every digit are present. Essentially it is equivalent to problem of distributing 4 balls among 9 (or 10) bins and can be easily solved by [stars and bars method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

If the sequence is non-decreasing it - as you have correctly noted - cannot contain $0$. This means we have choice between $9$ digits, so that the overall count is
$$
\binom{4+9-1}4=\binom{12}4=495 (\color{red}{\ne423}).\tag1
$$
If the sequence is non-increasing it can contain up to three $0$. Thus we have choice between $10$ digits, one choice ($0000$) being invalid, so that the count is:
$$
\binom{13}4-1=714(\color{red}{\ne552}).\tag2
$$

Together it gives (here you correctly defined the intersection of both sets):
$$\binom{12}4+\binom{13}4-10=1200.
$$

As seen from (1) and (2) your expressions heavily underestimate the actual numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much . I really appreciate you help .

Comment: You are welcome. Let me know if you need help in finding the error in your calculations.

Comment: I tried to find my error , then I realized in non-increasing part i made a mistake about calculating 0s being involved. My new answer to that part is 219(in a logical way) . When I add 219 (0 being involved ) to 0 not being involved which is 423 as you mentioned , it is equal to 642. And 642 is 72 units less than the correct answer 714 . Also 423 is 72 units less than 495. So my conclusion is that I’m doing the 0 being involved part correct but I’m missing somthing about 0 not being involved in non-increasing part .

Comment: and ${\binom 9 2}=72$ so i think I’m missing somthing in calculating possible ways of constructing a four digit number with 2 integers (when 0 is not invloved).

Comment: You are correct. The error is there. The factor should be 3 instead of 1.

Comment: $1112,1122,1222$